# syntax error near unexpected token `|'

Tags: arrays, bash, ssh, awk, pipe

I try to write a bash code and I am using command substitution. My code is like:

```
#!/bin/bash

IP="10.0.0.1 10.0.0.2"
PORT="22 80"
USERNAME="admin"
SCRIPT_HOST="adminHost"
HOME_DIR=/home/admin
SCRIPT_DIR=$HOME_DIR/scripts
script="sudo /my_remote_script.sh"
SSH="/usr/bin/ssh -t -o ConnectTimeout=10 -l ${USERNAME} ${SCRIPT_HOST}"

declare -a array1
declare -a array2
declare -a array3


for ip in ${IP} ; do
    for port in ${PORT} ; do

    rmt_command1=" $script -i $ip -p $port | awk -v IGNORECASE=1 '/pattern1/ {print \$4}' "

    rmt_command2=" $script -i $ip -p $port  | awk -v IGNORECASE=1 '/pattern2/ {print \$5}' "

    rmt_command3=" $script -i $ip -p $port | awk -v IGNORECASE=1 '/pattern3/ {print \$5}' "

    array1[$ip,$port]=$($SSH "$rmt_command1")
    array2[$ip,$port]=$($SSH "$rmt_command2")
    array3[$ip,$port]=$($SSH "$rmt_command3")

    done
done

for ip in ${IP}

    for port in ${PORT}
    printf   ${array1[$ip,$port]}
    printf   ${array2[$ip,$port]}
    printf   ${array3[$ip,$port]}

done
```

And I receive an error message like:

```
./test_sh: line 20: syntax error near unexpected token `|'
./test_sh: line 20: ` rmt_command1=" $script -i $ip -p $port | awk -v IGNORECASE=1 '/pattern1/ {print \$4}' "'
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: If you want to perform a command, then the syntax is `var=$(command)`. With `rmt_command1=" $script ...` you won't get it.

Comment: `${IP}"` looks wrong - did you mean `"${IP}"` or `${IP}`?

Comment: yes ${IP}, corrected.

Comment: Note that associative arrays are declared with `declare -A` not `declare -a`

Comment: I don't see anything wrong syntactically. You may have some sort of odd whitespace prior to `rmt_command1`. It's a little long, but could you add the output of `hexdump -C script.sh` (where `script.sh` is your filename) to the question? We can edit out the irrelevant portions if/once we've found the problem.

Answer (score -1):

I've seen this problem without reading the error message :

> ```
> for ip in ${IP}
>
>      for port in ${PORT}
>          printf   ${array1[$ip,$port]}
>          printf   ${array2[$ip,$port]}
>          printf   ${array3[$ip,$port]}
>
> done
> ```

You are missing one `done` and two `do` :

```
 for ip in "$IP"; do
      for port in "$PORT"; do
          printf   "${array1[$ip,$port]}"
          printf   "${array2[$ip,$port]}"
          printf   "${array3[$ip,$port]}"
      done
 done
```

Then, `{}` on `${IP}` and `${PORT}` are useless if not, unlike double quotes.

Otherwise, for your error message, you could try to remove the spaces around the pipe (`|`).

Comment: The question, as posted, does not seem to have ever been missing the `do` or `done` keywords.

Comment: I quote the mistakes that I see, even if they come after the error message mentioned. Then, for the error message, I also provided a track with spaces which are potentially incorrectly formatted.

Comment: I missed the bottom of the script. That is, indeed, a problem, although it occurs too late to cause the syntax error provided. The spaces around `|` shouldn't be an issue, because it's just an string assignment. Something is interfering with the parsing of the entire statement.